# Standardizing numerical and encoding of categorical data for training boosted decision tree

Tags: boosting, gradient

Is there a "best practice" way of standardizing numerical and encoding of categorical data for training boosted decision tree? Both for classification and regression problems

Comment: Are you asking about standardizing as in translate and scale to zero mean and unit variance?

Answer (score 1):

First, you could pick a learner, that does support categorical splits such as the R `gbm` package (in contrary to `xgboost`).

You could simply randomly enumerate categories and treat as numerical. This procedure works surprisingly well. So if you prefer `xgboost`, you may just be lazy and simply convert/coerce your data.frame of mixed factors(categoricals) and numeric features into a numeric matrix and pass to `xgboost`.

*One hot encoding* means each category gets a dummy variable and is either zero or one. This method only allow one-vs-all splits. I would try first two options first.

Sometimes your feature have numerous number of categories. It is often not as useful to simply plug-in such a feature into the model by any method. It may be worth to cluster the categories with kmeans and/or cautiously bin(few bins, to avoid over-fitting) the categories by naively expected target value.